# autotools: Makefile.am: link if file exists

Tags: c++, makefile, autotools, automake, ldflags

my Makefile.am creates the executable main: "symplerTest" i want to link the files "geometry/source/*.o". Currently im linking it like this:

```
symplerTest_LDFLAGS = \
    ...
    geometry/source/*.o
```

That works. But now in a next step, i want to link only if the files *.o exist. I tried this one:

```
if ("$(wildcard $(geometry/source/*.o))","")
symplerTest_LDFLAGS += geometry/source/*.o
endif
```

but get the following error message:

```
srcUnittest/Makefile.am:81: error: endif without if
srcUnittest/Makefile.am:79: warning: wildcard $(geometry/source/*.o: non-POSIX variable name
srcUnittest/Makefile.am:79: (probably a GNU make extension)
```

The problem seems to be at ("$(wildcard $(geometry/source/*.o))","")

Thank you!

Comment: I suspect this is an XY question.  Why in the world would you designate `.o` files to the linker in an Automake project?  Are these not intermediate build targets?  Ordinarily, you would control which objects are linked into the executable by controlling which sources are assigned to it, and let Automake sort out the details.  There are other alternatives, such as building and relying up on convenience libraries, but if your `Makefile.am` says anything at all about `.o` files directly then you're very likely on a suboptimal path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing the Automake directive [`if`](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Usage-of-Conditionals.html#Usage-of-Conditionals) with the Make
directive [`ifeq`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Syntax.html),

The Automake manual at [20 Conditionals](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Conditionals.html#Conditionals)
emphasises:

> Automake supports a simple type of conditionals.
>
> These conditionals are not the same as conditionals in GNU Make. Automake 
>   conditionals are checked at configure time by the configure script, and affect 
>   the translation from Makefile.in to Makefile. They are based on options passed 
>   to configure and on results that configure has discovered about the host system.
>   GNU Make conditionals are checked at make time, and are based on variables 
>   passed to the make program or defined in the Makefile.

`if` is not a Make directive at all. `ifeq` is a Make directive for which valid
arguments may be of the form `(arg1, arg2)`.

```
ifeq (arg1, arg2)
```

means, to Make, *if* `arg1` *is equal to* `arg2`.

Arguments of the form `(arg1, arg2)` are invalid for the Automake directive `if`.
Valid arguments for the Automake `if` directive are Automake condition-names,
e.g.

```
if DEBUG
```

means, to Automake, *if the condition named by* `DEBUG` *is true* - where
`DEBUG` is a condition name that you have previously created by means
of the [`AM_CONDITIONAL`](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Usage-of-Conditionals.html)
macro.

Refer to the linked documentation.

Comment: Thank you for answering! So there is no possibility to do something i just want to do? "Link if file exists"?

Comment: @mudi_lou John Bollinger's comment on your post applies. What you are trying to is the wrong solution to some other problem that you haven't explained. You should ask a new question about *that* problem.